# Is the force applied by us conservative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Is the force applied by human beings on one another conservative or non conservative? I think it should be conservative since the force applied by us is of the electromagnetic type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a force is conservative the work done by it in moving a object is independent of the path taken.  If the force one person applies on another were conservative then you could lift someone up, put them back down, and end up with the same energy you started with.  Which means you could keep picking them up and putting them down indefinitely without getting tired - clearly this is not the case.

It's true that the force a person applies is, at the level of fundamental forces, electromagnetic in nature.  So, why is it not conservative?  Because the two people are not simple single charges like two electrons, instead they are made up of billions of particles.  If you were to somehow analyze the work done on every single particle you would find the electromagnet force is still conservative but, at the macroscopic scale the second law of thermodynamics comes in and there are irreversible energy losses.

Answer (score -2):

No,It is not conservative force as there also act some dissipative force like frictional force.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 I'm pretty sure it is an answer.

Comment: @DavidZ: Well, okay.

Comment: when a dissipative force exist a path is not reversible i.e  that process would be non-conservative.